# BadLoginError deluged

Tags: server, 16.04, deluge

I have a problem to start deluged daemon on Ubuntu 16 server.
When I try to start it with `systemctl start deluged`, and then I check it with `systemctl status deluged` it gives me this error:

```
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: deluged.service: Unit entered failed sta
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: deluged.service: Failed with result 'exi
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: deluged.service: Service hold-off time o
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: Stopped Deluge Bittorrent Client Daemon.
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: deluged.service: Start request repeated 
Jun 20 10:13:48 Quel-Server systemd[1]: Failed to start Deluge Bittorrent Client
```

After that I try to start deluged daemon with `/usr/bin/deluged -d`, but with no success:

```
[ERROR   ] 10:16:04 rpcserver:266 Username does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/rpcserver.py", line 260, in dispatch
    ret = component.get("AuthManager").authorize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/authmanager.py", line 87, in authorize
    raise BadLoginError("Username does not exist")
BadLoginError: Username does not exist
[ERROR   ] 10:16:04 rpcserver:266 Username does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/rpcserver.py", line 260, in dispatch
    ret = component.get("AuthManager").authorize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/deluge/core/authmanager.py", line 87, in authorize
    raise BadLoginError("Username does not exist")
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue. I solved it by locating the deluged "auth" file (`/var/lib/deluge/.config/deluge/auth` in my case) and adding a new user there:

```
localclient:0cblablablablablaandmoreblaed5f:10
my_username:a_secret_password:10
```

More info in [Deluged Authentication docs](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Authentication)

Answer (score 2):

For those who are getting this problem you can check within:

- If you are using systemd and had previously installed with Upstart and/or System V init
- If you find-out a username and password for the login attempt in `systemctl status deluge-web` command
- Have followed the guide provided here: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/systemd

Then, this answer might help you !

---

1. close all services deluged, `deluge-webui` (through `systemctl` to be sure).
2. remove the `.config` folder from your user like root or other.
3. Modify the `hotlists` file located in `/var/lib/deluge/.config` folder. You might see that kind of info:

   ```
   "localhost", 
      58846, 
      "root or your username", 
      "somepassword"
   ```

   simply remove the username and password and set these as:

   ```
   "localhost", 
     58846, 
     "", 
     ""
   ```
4. Then restart deluged then `deluge-web` through `systemctl` and your daemon might appear online on the web-ui interface.